# WebService Client Exception: Cannot Import wsdl:binding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, compiler-errors

I got the following errors/warnings in the WebService Client program.

I was told that after if I remove the protocols, such as HTTP/GET and HTTP/POST from my web.config, it should work. But I'm using Windows Form.

How can I do the same in Windows Form?

```
Warning 1 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.webserviceX.NET']/wsdl:binding[@name='countryHttpGet'] C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PublicWebService\PublicWebService\Service References\CountryInfoWebSrv\Reference.svcmap 1 1 PublicWebService

Warning 2 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.webserviceX.NET']/wsdl:binding[@name='countryHttpGet']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.webserviceX.NET']/wsdl:service[@name='country']/wsdl:port[@name='countryHttpGet'] C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PublicWebService\PublicWebService\Service References\CountryInfoWebSrv\Reference.svcmap 1 1 PublicWebService

Warning 3 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.webserviceX.NET']/wsdl:binding[@name='countryHttpPost'] C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PublicWebService\PublicWebService\Service References\CountryInfoWebSrv\Reference.svcmap 1 1 PublicWebService

Warning 4 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.webserviceX.NET']/wsdl:binding[@name='countryHttpPost']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.webserviceX.NET']/wsdl:service[@name='country']/wsdl:port[@name='countryHttpPost'] C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PublicWebService\PublicWebService\Service References\CountryInfoWebSrv\Reference.svcmap 1 1 PublicWebService
```

Comment: Where did you get the WSDL document? What type of service WSDL document describes? WSDL is used only for SOAP services. WCF supports SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 services which don't use HTTP GET.

Comment: This is the link of the web service that I am using http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use svcutil for generating service proxy you have to remove everything related to http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http namespace wich is prefixed as http. So you need to remove two bindings and to web service ports. In that case you will also not need two port types and several message types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having 2 projects consuming same wcf, then remove the second reference and comment the code where you use the same. You can consume the same after updating the service in the first project.